# Qi Charging transmitter types

Tags: wireless-charging

I am working on a Qi Transmitter project and I have found that the Qi transmitter that I am using is not able to charge Iphones and Samsung phones at the 7.5 W that it should be able to. I am using the Qi 15W capable P9242-R which is a transmitter type of MP-A2, all the 7.5W capable iphone/samsung transmitter designs are MP-A11 or MP-11a according to the Qi product search page. the P9242-R seems to charge the Iphone at a 5W rate.

I have read the Qi Spec but there doesn't seem that much of a difference between the MP-A2 and the MP-A11 transmitter design.

- What is the difference between the MP-A2 and the MP-A11?
- Are the MP-A11 and MP-11a the only transmitter types capable of transmitting 7.5W to iphones/samsung phones?
- Are there different RX designs that only work with a certain TX designs extended power profiles(EPP)? or will all (EPP) RX work with most EPP TX designs?

Comment: http://www.big-bit.com/meeting/2018znkc/images/hhbd/dongzhi.pdf

Comment: http://gbtp.or.kr/wireless/upload//20171110025634271.pdf

Comment: Thanks Tony, I have read the spec, it is still not clear the difference between A2 and A11. Also the Toshiba presentation doesnot make it clear either. The toshiba device can be a 15W A2 or a 5 W A11? Does this require a board change or is it just a software change?

Comment: P27 OF toshiba spec defines the difference as 5V vs 12V input for starters

Comment: I dont think all A11 require the input voltage to be 5V., I just think that was just that designs input.

Comment: To get more than 5W , you need more than 5V on the Tx with A2 and negotiate from a higher power Rx.  The qualified result has adequate efficiency to keep temp rise within specs.

Comment: Extended  Power  Profile supporting the transfer  of  up  to  about  15W  of  power  using  an  appropriate  Secondary  Coil  (having  a typical outer dimension of around 40mm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple decided to deviate from QI standards. 7.5W is not a normal QI rate, and you cannot get 7.5W charging without apple specific protocol. Apple devices will work at the 5W rate.
https://www.zdnet.com/article/iphone-and-android-wireless-charger-pads-which-one-is-the-best/

Samsung also did the same for their high speed charging. WPC/QI charging is limited to 5W. You need Samsung fast wireless charging v1 or v2. https://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/what-is/fast-wireless-charging/

So your P9242-R QI 1.2 design can do 15W, but Apple and Samsung both don't care about that.